# SQL AVG with several category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple a table1 with

```
columnA     columnB
5            a
10           b
20           c
```

My goal to get the `avg` result on new `columnC` like this

```
columnA     columnB     columnC
5            a           .14
10           b           .29
20           c           .57
```

My query but did not get avg (each row columnA / total columnA)

```
select avg(columnA) as columnC
from table1
```

Not sure how to fix this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your required results are correct, because in that case you are not looking for an average, you are looking for a proportion of total.

So you want to divide your `columnA` value by the total for `columnA`, for which you can use a window function to obtain e.g.

```
declare @MyTable table (columnA int, columnB varchar(1));

insert into @MyTable (columnA, columnB)
    values
    (5, 'a'),
    (10, 'b'),
    (20, 'c');

select *
    , convert(decimal(9,2), columnA * 1.0 / sum(columnA * 1.0) over ()) columnC
from @MyTable;
```

Returns:

| columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | a | 0.14 |
| 10 | b | 0.29 |
| 20 | c | 0.57 |

Note: Because your values are integers you need to convert them to decimal (*1.0) in order to get a decimal result. And then I have added a further convert to restrict the decimal places to 2.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I though function AVG can do the job but not.

Comment: If you read up on the documentation, AVG gives the average for a column over a number of rows, so to use it you either need to use `group by` to aggregate some rows OR you need to use the window function version of avg which uses the `over` clause, However you are actually using the wrong term, you are not looking for an average, you are looking for a percentage proportion of the total. So that also added to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called 'proportion of total', one way to do it:

```
select columnA, columnB, cast(columnA/SumOfColumnA as decimal(15,2)) as columnC
from table1
     cross join
     (
       select sum(cast(columnA as float)) as SumOfColumnA from table1
     ) as SumCA
```

or, without cross join

```
select 
      columnA
    , columnB 
    , cast(columnA /
          (select sum(cast(columnA as float)) as SumOfColumnA from table1) as decimal(15,2)
          ) as columnC
from table1
```

Challenge accepted @DaleK (just kidding, you piqued my curiosity): I created a real table, and inserted 100K rows similar to the ones in the example here, and did an actual execution plan compare. When submitted as a batch, the query with windowing function reported the actual cost as 67% of the batch (ie it performed worse). Admittedly I didn't do anymore to see why.

[image: Execution plan compare]

The real life scenarios maybe quite different, of course.

Comment: Interestingly from a very basic performance check, this takes about twice as long as the window function version. Not that that is any reason not to use it.

Comment: Interesting again, thats all I did too... just less rows.